# The creation and annihilation operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

**What is the result of the commutation relation between the creation operator and a power of the annihilation operators in simple harmonic oscillator problem?**

Comment: In the book named quantum mechanics by Nouredine zettili  , you can see this topic in detail.

Answer (score 2):

$$[A,B^{2}]=[A,B]B-B[B,A]$$
Can you generalize that?